# Neighbours of a (subset of) vertex in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

[Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201120372) defines `neighborhood of v` as: 
$N(v) = {v} \  \bigcup \ \{w \in V | (v, w)\in E\}$.

shouldn't it be $N(v) = \{w \in V | (v, w)\in E\}$.

Comment: At best, my guess would be $\{v\}\cup \{w\in V\,\mid\, (v,w)\in E\}$ or, even better, $\{w\in V\,\mid\, (v,w)\in E\lor w=v\}$. Neighbourhoods of a point must contain it.

Comment: Sometimes the graph theoretic neighborhood includes the point in question, sometimes it doesn’t. One must check the definitions of whatever work one is studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commonly, graph theorists refer to the neighborhood set of a vertex $v$ as: $N(v) = \{ w \in V : vw \in E \}$. The closed neighborhood of a vertex, $N[v] = N(v) \cup \{v\}$. It looks like your book is referring to the closed neighborhood.

Note: Here, the terms *open* and *closed* are not in a topological context.